# Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

This query consists of 2 related questions.
I need to wait for an element to be invisible before I go to next step, hence I tried to define a custom method as below:

```
public void waitToDisappear(long timeOutInSeconds, WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    wait.ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element));
}
```

When I call this method as `common.waitToDisappear(5, <WebElement>);`, I'm getting `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:`.
However, if I use locator method `new WebDriverWait(world.driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath(someXpath))))`, it is working fine without any exception.

Question-1: `NoSuchElementException` is ignored in Selenium implementation of `invisibilityOfElementLocated()`, but not in `invisibilityOf()`. Is there is any reason for this? But, I think this is why I'm getting exception. How do I wait for an element(not locator) to be disappeared?

Question-2: Why am I getting `NoSuchElementException` even though I'm using `wait.ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);`. Is it the right way of using `wait.ignoring`? It seems that `wait.ignoring()` is not doing anything here.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### invisibilityOf()

[**`invisibilityOf(WebElement element)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOf(WebElement element)

An expectation for checking the element to be invisible
```

Here the expectation is that, the element must be **present** as well as **visible** as a pre-condition and the method will wait for the element to be **invisible**. At this point it is worth to mention that as the argument is of type *WebElement*, `findElement(By by)` have to successfully locate the element as a pre-condition. Hence `NoSuchElementException` can't be **ignored**.

---

### invisibilityOfElementLocated()

[**`invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)

An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.
```

Here the expectation is clearly either the element is already **invisible** or **not present** in the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). In this case the primary mission is the **absence** of the element which may occur even before the *ExpectedCondition* is invoked or during the *timespan* while the *ExpectedCondition* is active. So here we need to ignore `NoSuchElementException` as a mandatory measure.

---

Answering *Question-2*: Using `wait.ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);` isn't justified as the pre-condition of invoking `invisibilityOf(WebElement element)` involves the fact that the element must be present in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as a mandatory measure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm trying to wait for a "loading" (as soon as I get into a page, this element is visible until all the data is displayed) element to be disappeared before I click on another element. I can see that `visibilityOf(element)` is returning true (that means element is found), but `invisibilityOf(element)` is throwing `NoSuchElementException`.