# How to wait for an item to finish loading?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Well, I'm testing on a page designed in Angular and Java with Selenium. When a query is made to the database or the page loads in its code this appears:

```html
<span _ngcontent-c0 class = "loading"> </span>
```

When it finishes loading, it changes like this:

```html
<span _ngcontent-c0 class = "loading" hidden> </span>
```

My problem is that this "loading" is intercepting the clicks that I sent in the test:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a class="white-text" id="aaidEntidadBancaria" title="Apply"> ... </a> is not clickable at point (460, 502) . Other element would receive the click: <span _ngcontent-c0 = "" class = "loading"> </span>
```

what kind of wait could i use? I already tried invisibilityOfElementLocated (locator) but it didn't work ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the **loader** to be *invisible* or *hidden* inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.loading")));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']")));
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882118/selenium-invisibilityofelement-method-throwing-nosuchelementexception-webdri/51884408#51884408)

---

Once the **loader** is *invisible* or *hidden* you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and invoke `click()` as follows:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.loading")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.white-text#aaidEntidadBancaria[title='Apply']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='white-text' and @id='aaidEntidadBancaria'][@title='Apply']"))).click();
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)… Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)

Answer (score 0):

If `invisibility_of_element_located` is not working for you, you can try to work around the `ClickIntercepted` issue by using Javascript click:

```
# locate clickable element
clickable_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Apply']")))

# click with Javascript
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickable_element)
```