# Selenium Python: Element not clickable because another element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to click on a button that is either not yet clickable or has another element on top of it.

But as soon as it is clickable, I want to press it.
I tried this:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "likeClick")))
button.click()
```

But it doesnt work because I still get the error

````
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a class="likeClick"> is not clickable at point (400,553) because another element <div class="delete-overlay"> obscures it```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium-Debugging: Element is not clickable at point (X,Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879010/selenium-debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y)

Comment: @Prophet It shouldn't as this usecase is _ElementClickInterceptedException_ where as the dup target is about _WebDriverException_.

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <a class="likeClick"> is not clickable at point (400,553) because another element <div class="delete-overlay"> obscures it
```

...implies that the click to the `<a>` element failed as the element was obscured the `<div>` element which seems to be an temporary ***overlay*** .

---

### Solution

To click on the desired element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*invisibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70211530/7429447) of the [overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59095109/7429447) and then induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.delete-overlay")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.likeClick"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='delete-overlay']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='likeClick']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```