# Visibility of spinner is getting status true but after spinner dismiss invisibility of spinner is not working as expected

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am automating a web application with selenium c#.

After login I have to handle a spinner which appears in the home page.

I have given explicit wait

wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(LocatorSelect(locator, locatorvalue)));

And the result is getting passed and script wait for the element to be visible.

But after validating the spinner visibility I am validating the invisibility of the same element.

But the element still waits more than 30-40 seconds even if I have given 10 seconds. Then after around 40 seconds it is not throwing any error and continues to execute the script without any exception

```
public void Spinner_Check(string locator, string locatorvalue)
{
    int count = 1;

    WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    waits.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(LocatorSelect(locator, locatorvalue)));

    while (count > 0)
        {



        waits.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(locatorvalue)));
        IList<IWebElement> spinner_element = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(locatorvalue));
        int size = spinner_element.Count;
            if (size != 1)
            {
                count = 0;
                WriteLine("pass", "Spinner is dismissed for the page");
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

So how can I avoid that much wait time and execute the script soon after the spinner is dismissed from the page.

Few observations in the script:

1. When I inspect the html, when the element is visible, I could see style of the display attribute is 'Block'.But after spinner is dismissed from the UI, I could see, xpath showing no element in the search area : //iframe/parent::body//div[text()='Loading..']
2. For debugging purpose I had set wait for element visible after spinner dismissed from the page. Then I could see timeout exception and NoSuchElement exception triggered.

Comment: Update the question with the text based html of the spinner/loader element while loading and after loading completes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a few things:

- It's unclear if you have a seperate test to validate the *visibility of the spinner* but *invisibility of the spinner* is a valid usecase. So only `InvisibilityOfElementLocated()` may solve your purpose.
- `Spinner_Check` method looks as a complete overhead and you can replace it with just one line of code.

---

### Solution

To validate the [InvisibilityOfElementLocated](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm) e.g. the *spinner* you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(LocatorSelect(locator, locatorvalue)));
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussion in:

- [How to click on anchor element with selenium using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-anchor-element-with-selenium-using-python/59659543#59659543)
- [Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882118/selenium-invisibilityofelement-method-throwing-nosuchelementexception-webdri/51884408#51884408)

Comment: It is still waiting more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @BABURAJVD Can you check the `locatorvalue` and ensure it identifies the spinner uniquely when the spinner is active and visible?