# How to wait for an element to be contain the attribute style="display:none;" using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, display

When using Selenium/Python, I need to wait/pause until: `style="display:none;"` is displayed for a `<div id="notification"..</div>`

---

After clicking a button, the following is displayed (**Loading..**.)

`<div id="notification" class="notification_info" style="opacity: 1; display: inline-block;">Loading...</div>`

Then after a dataset is loaded in the web page, the **Loading...** goes away (by changing `display:none`), and the following is present:

`<div id="notification" class="notification_info" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>`

---

How would this be done (to check or wait on the value of `style="display: none;"`)?

Because there are many `<divs>` in the page with `style=display`, I need to wait on both the `id` of the `div`, and the `style display`.

Comment: Could you provide code and specify at which point you're stuck?

Comment: I don't have any code yet to solve this, I am stuck there.

Answer (score 4):

Once you click the desired button the element with text as `Loading...` becomes visible. Hence you see the element within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as:

```
<div id="notification" class="notification_info" style="opacity: 1; display: inline-block;">Loading...</div>
```

Once the loading completes the the element with text as `Loading...` is made invisible by changing the **`display`** property of the **`style`** attribute as:

```
style="display: none;"
```

Hence the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is represented in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as:

```
<div id="notification" class="notification_info" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
```

---

### Solution

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to wait for the the element with text as `Loading...` to turn as `style="display: none;"` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `invisibility_of_element()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.notification_info#notification")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notification_info' and @id='notification']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on anchor element with selenium using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-anchor-element-with-selenium-using-python/59659543#59659543)
- [Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882118/selenium-invisibilityofelement-method-throwing-nosuchelementexception-webdri/51884408#51884408)