# Selenium fails to detect password field

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, display, webdriverwait

If you visit: http://212.238.166.253:8080/

You will notice the following html element:

```
<input type="password" autocapitalization="off" autocomplete="off" value="" name="login_passwd" tabindex="2" class="form_input" maxlength="16" onkeyup="" onpaste="return false;" onblur="" placeholder="Password">
```

In python I wrote:

```
import time

import selenium.common.exceptions as SE
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

PASSWORD_XPATH = "//input[(@type='password') or (@type='Password') or (@type='PASSWORD')]"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(
        '/Users/algo/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/100.0.4896.60/chromedriver'))
    driver.get('http://212.238.166.253:8080/')
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, PASSWORD_XPATH)))
    except SE.TimeoutException:
        print('Nothing was Found!')
```

But all I get is:

```
Nothing was Found!
```

Why is that? I double checked and the page got directly fully uploaded, increasing timeout and sleep time didn't work either. Why the element wasn't found even though it's there?

Comment: Your xpath retrieves 2 elements try using a more restrictive one.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan why does that matter? I want to get any of the 2 but I get nothing...

Comment: @ArundeepChohan can you kindly help me understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *`@Arundeep Chohan`* mentioned the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) you have used identifies multiple elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

[image: multiple_ifame]

where the first matching element is having [***style="display: none;***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075070/7429447) and ofcoarse isn't your desired element.

```
<input name="foilautofill" style="display: none;" type="password">
```

Hence, *`Nothing was Found!`* gets printed.

---

The second matching node is your desired element

```
<input type="password" autocapitalization="off" autocomplete="off" value="" name="login_passwd" tabindex="2" class="form_input" maxlength="16" onkeyup="" onpaste="return false;" onblur="" placeholder="Password">
```

You need to construct canonical [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over) which identifies the desired element uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Solution

To locate the element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='password'][name='login_passwd']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password' and @name='login_passwd']")))
  ```

Comment: What I don't understand why in case of multiple matches Nothing Found is being printed? shouldn't it wait for first element to be clickable? if Not how can I do this?

Comment: If your method is looking out for a single webelement, the first matching element is returned irrespective of being visible/invisible, clickable/uninterectable. The solution is to construct a unique locator.

Comment: "the first matching element is returned" so why in my case even though the XPATH matches some, nothing found was printed?

Comment: Selenium can find the element but cannot focus on the element to send text due to the fact `style="display: none;`. Hence that isn't your desired element.

Comment: well I have added to the condition if the following doesn't exists in the field attributes: `style="display: none;` still same output.  Here try this: `PASSWORD_XPATH = "//input[((@type='password') or (@type='Password') or (@type='PASSWORD') or (@type='text' and contains(@style,'text-security')))" \
                 " and (not(@disabled)) and (not(contains(@class,'disabled')))" \
                 " and (not(contains(.,'display: none')))]"`

Comment: @Roi Seems you are messing up a couple of things. `display: none` isn't the innerText, rather it's the _style_ attribute. What's wrong with _`element_to_be_clickable()`_?

Comment: sorry I don't get you, can you kindly fix my xpath without changing its logic?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: I'm inside that room