# Using selenium in python to find and download file

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried searching for similar issues on the web but couldnt find an answer for this specific element of the website I am trying to access. A similar approach worked for other elements, hence trying to get some help please.

I would like to download the file located under the Download button there using Selenium in python
https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade

The button seems to be located under:

```
<span class="table-action-label" title="Download" data-i18n="[title]sgx-table.toolbar.action-download;[text]sgx-table.toolbar.action-download" data-i18n-options="{}">Download</span>
```

My code is

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
ua_rand = ua.random

print(ua_rand)


dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ua_rand

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("C://, desired_capabilities=dcap)
browser.get("https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='table-action-label']").click()


browser.quit()
```

But it doesnt seem to find the element

```
NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//span[@class='table-action-label']'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"119","Content-Type":"application/json
```

How could i download the file?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

did u try using this xpath : /html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/article/template-base/div/div/sgx-widgets-wrapper/widget-derivatives-nlt/section[1]/div[1]/sgx-table/sgx-table-toolbar/div[2]/span

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Download** you need to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `invisibility_of_element()` **sgx-loader**.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()`
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `LINK_TEXT`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.TAG_NAME, "sgx-loader")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Download"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.TAG_NAME, "sgx-loader")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.table-action-label[title='Download']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.TAG_NAME, "sgx-loader")))    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='table-action-label' and @title='Download'][text()='Download']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:
  [image: sgx]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [How to click on the anchor element when the spinner obscures it using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-the-anchor-element-when-the-spinner-obscures-it-using-selenium-a/59659543#59659543)
- [Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882118/selenium-invisibilityofelement-method-throwing-nosuchelementexception-webdri/51884408#51884408)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help, I have tried all 3 and get the same the result of a:
TimeoutException

I am using Phantomjs, could it be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

thank you both for your help, so far one version that works using google chrome is below. I am still trying to have it working using phantomJs.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
ua_rand = ua.random
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe")

driver2.get("https://www.sgx.com/derivatives/negotiated-large-trade")
WebDriverWait(driver2, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.TAG_NAME, "sgx-loader"))) 
time.sleep(5)
print("Downloading...")   
WebDriverWait(driver2, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='table-action-label' and @title='Download'][text()='Download']"))).click()

time.sleep(3)

driver2.quit()
```