# org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Can't run selenium tests on chrome browser 107 version

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

> 1. selenium version 4.5.3
> 2. webdriver manager version 5.3.0
> 3. my local
>    chrome version is 107.0.5304.87

Running tests locally on chrome(Mac OS), getting timeout exception on the `driver.get()` method.
The tests are successfully running on the firefox browser.

Also tried replacing webdriver manager with the downloaded 107 version of chromedriver- the same result.

```
15:41:34.598 INFO Using chromedriver 107.0.5304.62 (resolved driver for Chrome 107) 
15:41:34.618 INFO Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /Users/norayr.sargsyan/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/mac64/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver 

Starting ChromeDriver 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a5764881c92085aaee66d25075c159aa-refs/branch-heads/5304@{#942}) on port 21156
Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 31, 2022 3:41:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 107, so returning the closest version found: 106
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Build info: version: '4.5.3', revision: '4b786a1e430'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '11.0.10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [3c1f94f7071ec62f235edda9a3827a1f, get {url=https://vbs-dev-qa-auto.bynder.com}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 107.0.5304.87, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a576..., userDataDir: /var/folders/cb/jcvpr2vx6ln...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50070}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:50070/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 107.0.5304.87, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

Does anyone meet this issue and can help me to solve it?

The problem appears automatically when my local chrome browser updates to the new version, I tried to update to the latest versions of selenium and webdriver manager but didn't help.

Comment: I have come across this and never did find the exact cause.   For me it happened somewhat randomly. It seems to be a command timeout... timeout from browser to webdriver.  I was thinking it had to do with duplicate-named netty components in the Selenium Jar file... but was never able to confirm that.  (There were two same-named files in the jar, that were not actually the same file... so depending on what you chose during extraction (over-write or not) it would be different.)  Include your webdriver initialization code.  That may help narrow some things down.

Comment: Here's the thread where we were trying to figure this out (in the comments for the post): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73211822/selenium-4-and-webdriver-implicitlywait#comment129327052_73211822

Comment: You might try just try/catching the .get() call.  (If needed, retry in the catch... not so sure you'll have to though...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after chrome launch 110 version